# Horizontal UIView transition using gestures

Tags: iphone, uiview, gesture

ok, here goes....

When you gesture right or left on the iPhone home screen to access your pages of applications, you get a seamless transition between the current page of apps and the next one you're moving to.

I'd like to be able to create the feel of UIViews being almost 'stitched together' in the same way that different pages of apps are available on the iPhone home screen.

Is there a way to do this? Perhaps somewhere in one of the Apple sample code examples?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the way apple does it and the best way to do it is with UIScrollView, look at the the Page Control example app provided by apple here https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/index.html, you should be able to modify this to do what you want it to do...hope it helps!

Comment: Works nicely, however is it possible scroll/page a series of UIWebViews?

Comment: yea, instead of a view add a UIWebView

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to little success so far. Would you mind posting a code snippet? Thanks